# Sage Pay Direct intregration not working with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, opayo

I have created a Direct Payment method with Sage Pay and cards sucsesfully on my website however I seem to be stugling linking with paypal.

I am using the Direct method and using the php kits found here.
http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/direct-integration-documents

At the moment when a user selects PayPal my site correctly transfers the user to the PayPal site to make the payment, which they do and it then returns them back to my site. With this code.
/?vtx=lockers-PAYMENT-1422281021-294670621

I assume my site is bent to be listening and communicating with PayPal at this point to accept the transaction.

I am really lost where to go now. If anyone has worked with SagePay and Paypal I would really appreciate some pointers.

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear where you are going wrong, but it sounds as if once the payment is done and the consumer has been redirected back to your site, you need to send a COMPLETE post back to Sage Pay in order to finalise the process.

Worth checking in the paypal sandbox to check your transactions are appearing and that they are in the expected state (for a standard payment transaction), they will appear as pending until the COMPLETE post is received by Sage Pay (see above).